# UniData - record count of all files / tables

Tags: unidata, uniquery

Looking for a shortcut here. I am pretty adept with SQL database engines and ERPs. I should clarify... I mean databases like MS SQL, MySQL, postresql, etc.

One of the things that I like to do when I am working on a new project is to get a feel for what is being utilized and what isn't. In T-SQL this is pretty easy. I just query the information schema and get a row count of all the tables and filter out the ones having rowcount = 0. I know this isn't truly a precise row count, but it does give me an idea of what is in use.

So I recently started at a new company and one of their systems is running on UniData. This is a pretty radical shift from mainstream databases and there isn't a lot of help out there. I was wondering if anybody knew of a command to do the same thing listed above in UniBasic/UniQuery/whatever else.

Which tables, files, are heavily populated and which ones are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a special "table" (or file in Unidata terminology) named VOC - it will have a list of all the other files that are in your current "database" (aka account), as well as a bunch of other things.

To get a list of files in (or pointed to) the current account:

`:SORT VOC WITH F1 = "F]" "L]" "DIR" F1 F2`

Try `HELP CREATE.FILE` if you're curious about the difference between F and LF and DIR.

Once you have a list of files, weed out the ones named `*TEMP*` or `*WORK*` and start digging into the ones that seem important.  There are other ways to get at what's important (e.g using triggers or timestamps), but browsing isn't a bad idea to see what conventions are used.

Once you have a file that looks interesting (let's say CUSTOMERS), you can look at the dictionary of that file to see

`:SORT DICT CUSTOMERS F1 F2 BY F1 BY F2 USING DICT VOC`

It can help to create something like F2.LONG in DICT VOC to increase the display size up from 15 characters.

Now you have a list of "columns" (aka fields or attributes), you're looking for D-type attributes that will tell you what columns are in the file.  V or I-type's are calculations

https://github.com/ianmcgowan/SCI.BP/blob/master/PIVOT is helpful with profiling when you see an attribute that looks interesting and you want to see what the data looks like.

http://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20/unidata/previous%20versions/v8.1.0/unidata_userguide_v810.pdf has some generally good information on the concepts and there are many other online manuals available there. It can take a lot of reading to get to the right thing if you don't know the terminology.

Comment: Sorry, about the delay. Thanks a bunch!